# Fill larger dataframe from a smaller dataframe using identical column names

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am trying to merge two dataframes where one has duplicate column names and one with unique names. I am trying to fill in the empty larger one with values from the smaller one based on the column names but the merge or concat statement doesn't seem to work in this case

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=([1,2,3],[6,7,8]),columns=['A','B','C'])
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','B'])

# try to copy all rows from df to finaldf based on the column names
 
finaldf=pd.merge(df,finaldf) #MergeError: Data columns not unique: Index(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')

finaldf=pd.concat([finaldf,df],axis=0) #ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Comment: please provide a clear input/output example

Answer (score 0):

Would it help you to subset the smaller `df` with the column names of the empty wider `finaldf`?

```py
df[finaldf.columns]

   A  B  C  B
0  1  2  3  2
1  6  7  8  7
```